# Adding Keys and Values using 2 for loops in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary, collections

I am new to programming and more specifically dictionaries. I am trying to add keys using 1 for loop and add values using another for loop.

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary= new Dictionary<string, string>(); 


for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
    for(int j=32;j<45; j++)
myDictionary.Add(Convert.ToString(i)+"A", Convert.ToString(j)+"B");
```

I want to have 13 keys and 13 values but this produces more results that I intend to.

Can anyone help?

Comment: A dictionary entry contains a Tuple ie each contains 1 Key and 1 Value. You only need __one__ loop

Answer (score 3):

Have a single loop and add items like:

```
for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
{
   myDictionary.Add(Convert.ToString(i)+"A", Convert.ToString(i + 32)+"B");
}
```

You also don't have to call `Convert.ToString`, string concatenation can take care of that like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        myDictionary.Add(i + "A",  (i + 32) + "B");
```

Instead of nested for loop, you need a loop on two iteration variables. You can *also* do:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 32; i < 13 && j < 45; i++, j++)
    myDictionary.Add(i + "A", j + "B");
```

Comment: @EZI, umm yes, `4A` as Key and `36B` as value, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, one Linq projection:

```
var myDictionary = 
      Enumerable.Range(0, 13)
                .ToDictionary(i => i + "A", i => (i + 32) + "B");
```

Comment: Your approach is a neat one, easy and expressive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `value` is, being generated from such a loop.  However, you could in essence do the following:

```
var random = new Random();
var container = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(var i = 0; i < 13; i++)
     container.Add(i + "A", random.Next() + "B");
```

That code will automatically provide a numeric key of zero to thirteen.  Also, the value will be randomized and add a `B` to the end of those randomized values.